# Mask First & Last Name using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, dom-events, addeventlistener

I found this answer for masking a US phone number and it works fantastically:

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555"/>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to modify it to mask an input for first and last name where it will accept two strings of any length made up of only upper/lower alpha characters.

Javascript is not my strong suit and regex looks like matrix code to me, so I'm really hoping someone can put me in the right direction.

Comment: what kind of masking are you trying for the first and last name?

Comment: `of only upper/lower alpha characters.` for *names*? I guess you don't want Jean-Claude Van Damme to use that. Or Helena Bonham Carter. Or king T'Chala. [Among others](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Yeah, that's a really good point. I suppose I just want to be able to ensure this is A first and a last name present.

Comment: `.+` - checks for at least one character. Even that can be incorrect (people might not have a first name) but overall, it's probably the safest you can have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Regex matches a String with a first and last name separated by a white space. f.e. "John Doe"

```
([A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]*)
```